# SQL Trigger statement

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

### Given

**table1:**

> id|name

**table2:**

> id|table1_id|table3_id

**table3:**

> id|checked(type=BOOLEAN)

Now I want to delete the row in table2 when the corresponding row of table1 is deleted and the corresponding **table3** row is checked = true.

Which SQL statement do I have to use ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two triggers, one for detecting checked set to 1, one for checking deletion from table1. These are a bit "quick and dirty", but should work on any decently recent MySQL version.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trig_table1 AFTER DELETE ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE table2.*  
  FROM table2
  JOIN table3 
    ON table3_id = table3.id
   AND table3.checked = 1
   AND table1_id = OLD.id;
END;
//

CREATE TRIGGER trig_table3 AFTER UPDATE ON table3
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE table2.* 
  FROM table2
  LEFT JOIN table3 
    ON table3.id = OLD.id
   AND table3.checked = 0
  LEFT JOIN table1
    ON table1_id = table1.id
   AND table3_id = OLD.id
  WHERE table2.table3_id = OLD.id
    AND table3.id IS NULL
    AND table1.id IS NULL;
END;
//
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59452f/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, on MS SQL.

```
delete table2 from table2 inner join table3 on table2.table3_id = table3.id
left join table1 on table1.id = table2.table1_id
where table3.checked = true and table1.id is null
```